# Main differences between a Smart Home action and a DialogFlow action

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm just trying to figure out the main differences between these two types of actions. I mean a action that's use DialogFlow seems to be more conversational and more customizable. How does the Smart Home action handle the conversation? Is that a standard conversation based on the target device type?
When to create a Smart Home action and when to use DialogFlow?

Answer (score 1):

To understand the difference, you need to understand the difference between a smart home action and a conversational action.

#### Conversational Actions

This is where the user initiates a conversation with "talk to X". Your action gets a WELCOME event. Then the user says more things and your action needs to process the user query and provide a text-based response.

#### Smart Home Actions

With the [smart home integration](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/), the user just gives a command directly. "Turn on my lights," for example, without precluding that with a "talk to" statement. Another big difference is that Google processes the user's query directly. Your smart home action does not get the user's text. Instead, there's [a JSON request](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app) that specifies the user's intent.

The text that comes back is generated from Google as well, with parameters from your integration. Saying "turn on my lights" will result in "Ok, turning on lamp" or "Sorry, your lamp is offline" depending on what response your fulfillment sends.

There are a number of device types supported out of the box, as well as many [traits](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/). Traits specify the types of things that a device can do, such as turning on/off, or changing color. The traits are not explicitly tied to type, eg. you could change the color of a vacuum.

#### When to use each

If you're building or integrating a device that is meant to work with the Google Assistant, I'd suggest you look at smart home first. It will give users a better experience in being able to directly send queries, and it will make it easier for you to build fulfillment as the requests are structured already.

However, if it will not work for your application, you would want to look at Dialogflow, which will give you a greater level of flexibility in what the user can say.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. About smart home actions, I saw that each device type has a reccomended list of traits, I'm wondering, is it possible to add custom tratis to a device? About the conversation it's all handled by google? How does it know wich intent to trigger?
For example I have a refrigerator that gives you tips about eating well, this intent is trigger by a prhase specified by me. My question is how does a smart home know wich intent to trigger. It's related to adding custom tratis to a device type. Sorry for my english and thank you for the support!

Comment: Custom traits? Not really. You can use Modes or Scenes to do some custom handling. The conversation is handled by Google. Your webhook only gets the JSON request, chosen by Google's ML understanding of what the user wants. If you want something like a fridge that gives tips, you will need to build a conversational action or embed the Google Assistant into it with the Google Assistant SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support! Very clear explanation.

Comment: In my current project I need to use both smart home action and Conversational Action. my problem is User needs to sign in(For account linking ) both app separately. Is there way user can sign in once ??

Comment: No if you have two separate Actions there needs to be two separate sign-ins.